# Are there any verses in the Hebrew bible (or just the Torah) that show that God is indivisible?

Tags: tanach, theology

There are some monotheistic religions that believe that there is one god, but there are (or can be) parts to him (christianity is a good example). They don't believe that god is one and complete and indivisible.

Are there any verses in the tanakh or just the torah that prove that god is indivisible?

Some people use the verse "Hear o Israel: The Lord thy God is one god" as proof that god is one. But it doesn't necessarily contradict the idea that he can be divisible.

Comment: Some people say it does contradict that, "We believe that this Primal Cause [God] is One. [His is] not like the oneness of a pair, nor like the oneness of a species, nor like man, whose complex oneness may be divided into many units, nor like the oneness of a simple body, which is one in number but may be divided and separated without end. Rather, He is One with a Oneness that knows no parallel in any manner. This is the Second Principle, as affirmed by the verse (Deut. 6:4): "Hear O Israel, God is our Lord, God is One.""

Comment: Agreed, Danno,  As they said in Logic class and in an Ayn Rand book or two, ONE = ONE. No mothers, sons, uncles, brother-in-laws, etc. ONE.  Very easy.

Comment: The "Shema" verse that you cited doesn't seem to prove anything. It is a statement of faith. Offhand, I'm unaware of any Torah or Biblical verse that outright proves that G-d is one. It is a principle of belief. I think Maimonides, and Rav Moshe Chaim Lutzatto in "Derech Hashem" delve into a logical method primarily using "counter" proofs to explain how G-d is one.

Comment: The verse is "... Y-HVH is our G-d , Y-HVH is One"; your mistranslation holds most of your objection. (Nor "your", but "our". The whole point of "Listen, Israel" is that the peoplehood and being part of the community of believers is itself part of the doxology. But getting back on point...)

Comment: One of Maimonides' arguments is that the difference between One God with many parts and multiple gods is basically wording. Does the word "God" to refer to the whole or each part? Both open the door to having multiple targets of worship. Similarly, Rabbeinu Tam deals with the trinity halachically by identifying the Father with the Jewish G-d, and the other two persons as His assistants. And since the Noachide Covenant allows non-Jews to ascribe assistants, he can rule leniently in a number of questions about dealings with Christians.

Comment: Despite Rabbeinu Tam's analysis (which would be of 12th cent Catholic theology) not all Christians today believe that the trinity implies three parts. Many are much closer to Rav Saadia Gaon's analysis of the trinity -- three perceptions of an unfathomable Unity. That three-ness inheres in the human condition, giving us three ways to look at G-d, each giving us a different appearance.

But then, all of the Hindu gods are, deep down, different perceptions of a single, unfathomable, indivisible, Brahman. Here is a list of proof-texts http://www.islam101.com/religions/hinduism/conceptOfGod.htm